# symfony Notice: Array to string conversion choicetype multi dimensional

Tags: arrays, symfony, multidimensional-array

I have a problem with choicetype on symfony 2.8
I tried to do this

I change my event entity like this

```
    public function setDisciplineLevels($disciplines_to_order) {
    $levelsbydiscipline = array();
    foreach($disciplines_to_order as $disciplines) {
        if(!array_key_exists($disciplines['discipline'], $levelsbydiscipline)){
            $levelsbydiscipline[$disciplines['discipline']] = array();
        }    
        $levelsbydiscipline[$disciplines['discipline']][$disciplines['teacherdiscipline_id'].$disciplines['level_id']]= $disciplines['title'];

    }
    $this->disciplinelevels= $levelsbydiscipline;

    return $this;
}
```

My array result is :
[My array like sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9PF0.png)

the code in my form is

```
->add('disciplinelevels', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices_as_values' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                //'expanded' => true
            ));
```

but each time I have an error : Notice Array to string conversion

it seems the problem come from the method :
getDisciplineLevels

when I do this in the form the result is correct but i need to change the name
it's ok with level but not with disciplinelevels :

```
->add('level', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices'=>array('informatique' => array(
                    '123'=>'Debutant',
                    '345'=>'Confirme',
                    '678'=>'Expert'
                )),
                'choices_as_values' => false,
                'multiple' => false,
                'expanded' => false
            ));
```

[stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDAt4.png)

my entity event

```
<?php
```

namespace TR\CalendarBundle\Entity;

/**
 * Event
 */
class Event
{

```
const ORANGE = '#ff7043';
const RED = '#ff1744';
const PINK = '#E6007E';
```

//    Generated Code

```
/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 */
private $start;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 */
private $end;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $color;

/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $status;

/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $id_availability;

/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $participants_max;


/**
 * @var \TR\VisioBundle\Entity\Meeting
 */
private $meeting;

/**
 * @var \TR\MainBundle\Entity\School
 */
private $school;

/**
 * @var \TR\MainBundle\Entity\Teacher
 */
private $teacher;

/**
 * @var \TR\MainBundle\Entity\Discipline
 */
private $discipline;

/**
 * @var \TR\MainBundle\Entity\Level
 */
private $level;

/**
 * @var array
 */
private $disciplinelevels;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}



/**
 * Set start
 *
 * @param \DateTime $start
 *
 * @return Event
 */
public function setStart($start)
{
    $this->start = $start;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get start
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getStart()
{
    return $this->start;
}

/**
 * Set end
 *
 * @param \DateTime $end
 *
 * @return Event
 */
public function setEnd($end)
{
    $this->end = $end;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get end
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getEnd()
{
    return $this->end;
}

/**
 * Set color
 *
 * @param string $color
 *
 * @return Event
 */
public function setColor($color)
{
    $this->color = $color;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get color
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getColor()
{
    return $this->color;
}

/**
 * Set status
 *
 * @param integer $status
 *
 * @return Event
 */
public function setStatus($status)
{
    $this->status = $status;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get status
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getStatus()
{
    return $this->status;
}

/**
 * Set idAvailability
 *
 * @param integer $idAvailability
 *
 * @return Event
 */
public function setIdAvailability($idAvailability)
{
    $this->id_availability = $idAvailability;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get idAvailability
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getIdAvailability()
{
    return $this->id_availability;
}

/**
 * Set meeting
 *
 * @param \TR\VisioBundle\Entity\Meeting $meeting
 *
 * @return Event
 */
public function setMeeting(\TR\VisioBundle\Entity\Meeting $meeting = null)
{
    $this->meeting = $meeting;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set Participants_max
 *
 * @param \TR\VisioBundle\Entity\Meeting $participants_max
 *
 * @return Event
 */
function setParticipantsMax($participants_max) {
    $this->participants_max = $participants_max;
    return $this;

}

/**
 * Get meeting
 *
 * @return \TR\VisioBundle\Entity\Meeting
 */
public function getMeeting()
{
    return $this->meeting;
}

/**
 * Get Participants_max
 *
 * @return integer
 * 
 */

function getParticipantsMax() {
    return $this->participants_max;
}




/**
 * Set school
 *
 * @param \TR\MainBundle\Entity\School $school
 *
 * @return Event
 */
public function setSchool(\TR\MainBundle\Entity\School $school = null)
{
    $this->school = $school;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get school
 *
 * @return \TR\MainBundle\Entity\School
 */
public function getSchool()
{
    return $this->school;
}

/**
 * Set teacher
 *
 * @param \TR\MainBundle\Entity\Teacher $teacher
 *
 * @return Event
 */
public function setTeacher(\TR\MainBundle\Entity\Teacher $teacher = null)
{
    $this->teacher = $teacher;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get teacher
 *
 * @return \TR\MainBundle\Entity\Teacher
 */
public function getTeacher()
{
    return $this->teacher;
}

/**
 * Set discipline
 *
 * @param \TR\MainBundle\Entity\Discipline $discipline
 *
 * @return Event
 */
public function setDiscipline(\TR\MainBundle\Entity\Discipline $discipline = null)
{
    $this->discipline = $discipline;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get discipline
 *
 * @return \TR\MainBundle\Entity\Discipline
 */
public function getDiscipline()
{
    return $this->discipline;
}

/**
 * Set level
 *
 * @param \TR\MainBundle\Entity\Level $level
 *
 * @return Event
 */
public function setLevel(\TR\MainBundle\Entity\Level $level = null)
{
    $this->level = $level;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get level
 *
 * @return \TR\MainBundle\Entity\Level
 */
public function getLevel()
{
    return $this->level;
}

/**
 * Get levels by discipline
 *
 * @return \TR\MainBundle\Entity\Event
 */    
public function setDisciplineLevels($disciplines_to_order) {
    $levelsbydiscipline = array();
    foreach($disciplines_to_order as $disciplines) {
        if(!array_key_exists($disciplines['discipline'], $levelsbydiscipline)){
            $levelsbydiscipline[$disciplines['discipline']] = array();
        }    
        $levelsbydiscipline[$disciplines['discipline']][$disciplines['teacherdiscipline_id'].$disciplines['level_id']]= $disciplines['title'];

    }
    $this->disciplinelevels= $levelsbydiscipline;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get levels by discipline
 *
 * @return array
 */ 
public function getDisciplineLevels() {
    return $this->disciplinelevels;
}
```

}

Thanks for your help.
Fabrice

Comment: when you submit your form or before rendring the form you got the problem?
and can you show as your class if is it possible

Comment: What shall be the choice values (data submitted to backend) and the choice labels (names shown as choices) in your  example array? Shall the values be grouped by the first level key ( `Informatique` in the screenshot )?

Comment: The problem is before rendering the form witch class you need the entity ? And yes `Informatique` is the first level --> <optgroup> and the second level is the <option> same as the symfony documentation

Comment: The symfony doc I try to use is : [link]https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/choice.html#grouping-options[/link] @nifr

Comment: maybe provide stacktrace of where the issue lies, whether it is your form or the `setDisciplineLevels()` method. i have a feeling it is `$levelsbydiscipline[$disciplines['discipline']][$disciplines['teacherdiscipline_id'].$disciplines['level_id']]= $disciplines['title'];`

Comment: @andrew-nolan stack trace added in picture

Comment: When i try to use what you provided, I get `WARNING Illegal string offset 'discipline'` related to `if(!array_key_exists($disciplines['discipline'], $levelsbydiscipline))`

Comment: @andrew-nolan  it's "normal" because $discipline_to_order is an array like this `array:3 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "teacherdiscipline_id" => 1
    "discipline" => "Informatique"
    "title" => "Débutant"
    "level_id" => 29
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "teacherdiscipline_id" => 1
    "discipline" => "Informatique"
    "title" => "Confirmé"
    "level_id" => 30
  ]
  2 => array:4 [▼
    "teacherdiscipline_id" => 1
    "discipline" => "Informatique"
    "title" => "Expert"
    "level_id" => 31
  ]
]
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the controller call the method from the entity who convert the original array to multidimensional array

**** CONTROLLER ****

`$masterclass->setDisciplineLevels($disciplines_teacher_current);`

**** ENTITY ****

In the entity add to private attributes with getters and setters and a special method __toString to convert each result from the form to string the two last methods is for using in the form and show the select

```
/*
* @var array
*/
private $disciplinelevels;

/*
* @var string
*/
private $listdisciplinelevels;

/*
* @var string
*/

public function __toString() {
    return $this->listdisciplinelevels;
}

/* GETTERS AND SETTERS */

/*
* Get levels by discipline convert initial arrayt to multidimensionnal
*
* @return \TR\MainBundle\Entity\Event
*/

public function setDisciplineLevels($disciplines_to_order = array()) {
    $levelsbydiscipline = array();
    foreach($disciplines_to_order as $disciplines) {
        if(!array_key_exists($disciplines['discipline'], $levelsbydiscipline)){
            $levelsbydiscipline[$disciplines['discipline']] = array();
    }
        $levelsbydiscipline[$disciplines['discipline']][$disciplines['teacherdiscipline_id'].$disciplines['level_id']]= $disciplines['title'];

    }

    $this->disciplinelevels= $levelsbydiscipline;
    return $this;
}

/**
* Get levels by discipline
*
* @return array
*/ 
public function getDisciplineLevels() {
    return $this->disciplinelevels;
}

function getListdisciplinelevels() {
    return $this->listdisciplinelevels;
}

function setListdisciplinelevels($listdisciplinelevels) {
    $this->listdisciplinelevels = $listdisciplinelevels;
}
```

`
**** FORM ****

You need to get the class array you set before in the controller

`$eventinit = $builder->getData();`

And after you just need to create your choiceType element with the the name of the attribute use for the method __toString and call the multidimensionnal array with the getter's object

```
->add('ListDisciplineLevels', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'placeholder'=>'Do a choice',
    'choices' => $choice = $eventinit->getDisciplineLevels(),
    'choices_as_values' => false,
));
```